# Bijective vs Isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, analysis

They seem like they're used interchangeably all the time, for everything from group theory to real analysis. What's the difference?

Comment: Just a comment, I see a lot of people saying that an isomorphism is necessarily a bijection, which is not technically true, in the sense that in a general category it does not make sense, because morphisms cannot always be interpreted as functions between sets. In *concrete* categories, on the other hand, we can associate a function to each morphism, and there it is true that the function corresponding to an isomorphism is necessarily a bijection.

Answer (score 7):

A bijection is different from an isomorphism. Every isomorphism is a bijection (by definition) but the connverse is not neccesarily true.

A bijective map $f : A \rightarrow B$ between two sets $A$ and $B$ is a map which is injective and surjective. Because it is injective, no two elements in the domain $A$ are mapped to the same element in the co-domain $B$. Because it is surjective, each element in the co-domain $y \in B$ has an element in the domain $x \in A$ such that the element $y$ is mapped by the function $f$ i.e. $y = f(x)$. This means that all the elements in the co-domain $B$ are "hit" by the map and none are left over. Thus, there is a one to one correspondence between the elements of the set $A$ and the elements of the set $B$.

As an analogy. If you have $5$ seats and each seat is occupied by a different person, then you have a one to one correspondence (bijection) between the seats and the people. I.e. each seat is assigned and individual person and vice versa. No seat is left-over and you can say that person A belongs to seat 2, person B belongs to seat 1, etc.

An isomorphism is a bijective homomorphism. I.e. there is a one to one correspondence between the elements of the two sets but there is more than that because of the homomorphism condition. The homomorphism condition ensures that the algebraic operation(s)  are preserved. So i.e. when you perform addition in the algebraic structure $A$, you are also performing addition in the set $B$ and the result will be equivalent for the purposes of algebra. In other words, isomorphic spaces are equivalent and only differ in the nature of their objects but for the purposes of doing i.e. addition (or whatever algebraic operation is under consideration), it does not matter if you perform it in set $A$ or in set $B$.

As an analogy here. Think of doing addition with physical objects. Take apples and bananas. Let us say you have the same amount of apples and bananas. Performing addition with apples and performing addition with bananas gives the same result. Certainly, apples and bananas are not the same objects (i.e. differ in their nature), but for the purposes of doing addition it doesn't matter if you add 2 apples to 3 apples you get 5 apples; adding 2 bananas to 3 bananas you get 5 bananas. The result (quantity) will be the same.

Answer (score 2):

A bijection is an isomorphism in the category of Sets. When the word "isomorphism" is used, it is always referred to the category you are working in. I will list some categories including their typical names for isomorphism:

- Sets: Bijection
- Groups: Isomorphism
- Top: Homeomorphism
- Differentiable Manifolds: Diffeomorphism
- Riemannian Manifolds: Isometry

Answer (score 2):

From the categorical point of view isomorphism is the important notion. A *category* basically is a collection of objects together with a collection of arrows between them such that every object $X$ has an identity arrow $1_X:X\rightarrow X$ and there is a notion of composition of arrows $$X\xrightarrow{f}Y\xrightarrow{g}Z = X\xrightarrow{g\circ f}Z$$
Now an *isomorphism* in a category is an arrow $f:X\rightarrow Y$, for which there is an inverse arrow $g:Y\rightarrow X$ satsifying $g\circ f= 1_X$ and $f\circ g = 1_Y$.

There are many categories you may already know or will see later, commonly sets with additional structure. In all cases, isomorphism is the notion of „being the same in structure“, which is much weaker than „equality of objects“. When working with a specific category, there might be nice criterions of when an arrow is an isomorphism. For example

$$\begin{array}{lll}
\text{sets}&\text{functions}&\text{bijections}\\
\text{groups}&\text{group hom}&\text{bijective group hom}\\
\text{vector spaces}&\text{vector space hom}&\text{bijective vector space hom}\\
\text{simple graphs}&\text{graph hom}&\text{graph hom bijective on vertices and surjective on edges}\\
\text{topological spaces}&\text{continuous functions}&\text{bijective + bicontinuous functions aka homeomorphisms}\\
\text{metric spaces}&\text{contractions}&\text{isometries}\\
\text{Banach spaces}&\text{bounded linear operators}&\text{bijective bounded linear operators}\\
C^1-\text{manifolds}&\text{differentiable functions}&\text{differentiable function with differentiable inverse aka diffeomorphism}
\end{array}$$
Note that in the last case this *is* the very definition of an isomorphism.

Answer (score 0):

The concept of isomorphism varies from structure to structure. A bijective map $f$ between groups is an isomorphism if it is also  a homomorphism: $f(gh)=f(g)f(h)$ for all $g,h$. A bijective map between vector spaces is an isomorphism if it is also linear. An isomorhism between normed linear spaces is  a bijection that is linear and also a homeomorphism and so on.

Comment: Yes, isomorphisms are stronger: they are bijections with some extra property specific to the area.

Comment: So if you technically considered a vector space a group, one that satisfies closure, identity, associativity, then used addition, shouldn't an isomorphism have the same meaning and can there be non-linear isomorphisms of vector spaces?

Comment: @askmorequestionsagain2 You can have a bijection $f$ between two vector spaces $V$ and $W$ such that $f$ is a group isomorphism from $(V,+)$ onto $(W,+)$ but not a vector space isomorphism.

Comment: So a vector space isomorphism is even stronger than a group isomorphism?

Comment: Yes, and an isomorphism of Banach spaces is even  stronger; an isomorphism of Banach algebras goes one more step.

Comment: What generalizes an isomorphism if its very definition changes between structures?

Answer (score 0):

All isomorphisms are bijections, but not vice- versa.  Except in the category $\bf{\text{Set}}$, where they coincide.

Depending on the category, an isomorphism is a bijection which preserves the structure being studied.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of bijection and isomorphism being commonly used interchangeably.  A bijection is a map which is one to one and onto.  It need not preserve any structure that is present.  An isomorphism needs to preserve some additional structure.  What that additional structure is, depends on the context.

The only case where they would be interchangeable is if you were dealing with sets with no additional structure.  In that case, they would be the same as there is no additional structure.  However, it is rare to say isomorphism in this case.

A simple example of additional structure is a group.  This is a set with an operation, typically (but not always) written as multiplication.  In this case, an isomorphism must have the property $f(x \times y) = f(x) \times f(y)$.  In a sense, the existence of isomorphism means that (considered as groups), there is no interesting difference between them.

Consider the integers $\mathbb{Z}$ and the rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}$.  These can be considered as groups with addition as the operation.  There is a bijection between them as they are both countable.  However, no bijection also has the property $f(x + y) = f(x) + f(y)$ so there is no isomorphism.  These sets are interestingly different when considered as groups with addition.  There is an obvious map from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Q}$ with this property but it is not onto.  This is called a homomorphism.

It can get more complicated.  Rings which have two operations: addition and multiplication.  A map might preserve one operation and not the other.

Consider the complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$ with their usual operations and $\mathbb{R}^2$ with pointwise operations: $(a, b) + (c, d) = (a + c, b + d)$ and $(a, b) \times (c, d) = (a \times c, b \times d)$.  There is an obvious bijection between the two.  Is there an isomorphism?  If you asked just "are these isomorphic?" then you would probably get the answer no.  The responder would probably assume that since you have mentioned two operations that the isomorphism should preserve both.  A more pedantic answer would be that they are isomorphic as groups with the addition operation but that they not isomorphic as rings with both operations.  If confusion is likely then you should specify what you mean.

Finally some pedantry.  Another difference between "bijective" and "isomorphism" is that bijective is an adjective but isomorphism is a noun.  It would be better to ask "bijective v isomorphic" or "bijection v isomorphism".